# Setting div height by calculating .attr() values

Tags: jquery, class, attributes

Happy New Year.

I am attempting to set the height of a div by calculating the .attr() values of a series of elements.

The html

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="add-x">Add X</div>
    <div id="most-x">Most X</div>
    <div id="least-x">Least X</div>
    <div id="add-class">Add Classes</div>
</div>

<div id="calculate">
    <div class="add-x a" x="10">Sample Text</div>
    <div class="add-x b" x="20">Sample Text</div>
    <div class="add-x c" x="30">Sample Text</div>
    <div class="add-x d" x="40">Sample Text</div>
    <div class="add-x e" x="50">Sample Text</div>
</div>

<div id="height-box">Height Box</div>
```

The js

```
var total = null;

$('#add-x').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#calculate .add-x').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).attr('x')); 
    });
alert(total) 
});

var most = null;

$('#most-x').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#calculate .add-x').each(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('x'));
    most = (value > most) ? value : most;       
    });    
alert(most)  
});

var least = null;

$('#least-x').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#calculate .add-x').each(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('x'));
    least = (value < least) ? value : least; 
    });   
alert(least)  
});
```

Additionally I would like to set a value for the letter classes (class a=10px, class b=20px , class c=30px, class d=40px and class e=50px) and have them calculated as total, greatest and smallest values in the same way as the .attr()'s are. The aim here is to not use attributes in the html possibly.

My questions are:

1). How do get the least value of .attr('x') in the same way that I am getting the greatest value?

2.) How do I store this in a var so that I can apply it on an element's height using .on()?

3.) How do I assign a value to a class and then calculate it using .on(), and have it determine an element height?

Here's where I'm at: http://jsfiddle.net/ifthatdoesntdoit/chQdK/58/

Thanks

Comment: Just fyi, if you have multiple questions that are unrelated (even if they are in the same code), please be sure to ask multiple questions, and not ask them all in one.  Different experts can focus on individual problems; it is far easier for you to title the questions correctly; and if there are mutiple correct responses for each different question, how do you make just one of them the "correct" answer?

Comment: Will do, iND. Thanks for the heads up. I'll keep this in mind moving forward. Thanks for the response. I'm still going to use this eventually but haven't gotten around to it. As soon as I am able to work on it again I will accept an answer. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Scoping on the total.  Change to this

```
var total = 0;

$('#add-x').on('click', function(event) {
   total = 0;
    $('#calculate .add-x').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).attr('x'));
    });
   alert(total);
});
```

and this sets most height:

```
var most = 0;

$('#most-x').on('click', function(event) {
    most = 0;
    $('#calculate .add-x').each(function() {
        var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('x'));
        most = (value > most) ? value : most;

    });
    alert(most);

    $('#height-box').height(most);

});
```

and least:

```
$('#least-x').on('click', function(event) {
    least = 1000000;
    $('#calculate .add-x').each(function() {
        var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('x'));
        least = (value < least) ? value : least;

     });

     alert(least)
     $('#height-box').height(least);

});
```

The other things you want should really be asked in a separate question.  Too many things to answer, so it's hard to focus answers. . . .

Comment: iND- Thanks for the help. However, after pasting in your code nothing is happening on clicking the total, most and least buttons. My js experience is limited so please be patient. Here's the latest jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ifthatdoesntdoit/chQdK/68/ Can you maybe update the example and get it working? -Thanks

Comment: The problem was typos -- sorry!  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code answering all your questions. Please read the comments in the code. Hope that helps.

```
<div id="calculate">
<div class="10px">Sample Text</div>
<div class="20px">Sample Text</div>
<div class="30px">Sample Text</div>
<div class="40px">Sample Text</div>
<div class="50px">Sample Text</div>
</div>


var total = null,
    $calculateDiv = $('#calculate div'),
    $heightBox = $('#height-box'),
    once = true;

$('#add-x').on('click', function(event) {
    if(once) { //Calculate total only once.
        $calculateDiv.each(function() {
            total += parseFloat($(this).attr('class'));
            once = false;
        });  
    } 
    $heightBox.height(total); // Set the height of green box after calculating total
});



var most = null;

$('#most-x').on('click', function(event) {
    $calculateDiv.each(function() {
        var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('class'));
        most = (value > most) ? value : most;

     }); 

$heightBox.height(most); // Set the height of green box after calculating 'most'

});


var least = null;


$('#least-x').on('click', function(event) {
    least = parseFloat($calculateDiv.eq(0).attr('class')); // Set it to the first value before comparing.
    $calculateDiv.each(function() {
        var value = parseFloat($(this).attr('class'));
        least = (value < least) ? value : least;

     }); 

    $heightBox.height(least); // Set the height of green box after calculating 'least'

});
```

Comment: Sandeep- Thanks for checking out my code. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it working. My experience with js is limited so I appreciate your patience.  Here's the latest jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ifthatdoesntdoit/eGtXp/3/ Would you mind trying to get it to work. On Alert() I am only getting 'NaN' and null. -Thanks

Comment: There, I have fixed it. Be wary, you cannot have any other class name for DIVs in `#calculate` div. If you want to avoid non-standard attributes, how about using 'rel' attribute instead of class?